# Lights off and on in website background when playing video player on my website

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a website where i can stream video and I'm planning to make a button to turn off and on the background website but not include the video. Can anyone help me with the javascript code? Thank you very much.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.video').allofthelights({
        'opacity': '0.7',
        'delay_turn_on': '3000',
        'custom_player': "iframe[src^='http://mycoolvideosite.com'], iframe[src^='http://myviiids.com']",
        'callback_turn_off': function() {
            $("h1").addClass('light');
        }
    });
});
```

I am trying to use this code but i don't understand about the iframe and the html on how should i put it.

Comment: This question is **way** too broad, you haven't provided any code, etc. What do you need help with *specifically*?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any research, code etc. Or are you asking for a starting point to go from? (Or are you asking someone to do everything for you?)

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.video').allofthelights({
        'opacity': '0.7',
        'delay_turn_on': '3000',
        'custom_player': "iframe[src^='http://mycoolvideosite.com'], iframe[src^='http://myviiids.com']",
        'callback_turn_off': function() {
            $("h1").addClass('light');
        }
    });
});

I am trying to use this code but i don't understand about the iframe and the html on how should i put it.

Comment: Alvian, you've submitted this as an answer but it should really be an update to your question. I've gone ahead and done this for you - please consider deleting this answer if you wouldn't mind.